# NativeBase - Content size and switching tab issues

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm building a React Native app using some of Native Base components. Its footer and header are good and easy to understand, but I'm having 2 issues about `<Content>` size and position.

**Issue 1:**

[image: End of screen]

When I scroll down, then click, for example, "First Element" in the TimeTable section, which is a `<Accordion>` (kind of drop down list for one who doesn't know), then the size of content gets longer, but the screen doesn't update to fit the whole content.

[image: The "Lesson 5" button is lost!]

My code is not special, I don't give any style for `<Container>` and `<Content>` so I think this is its default. I once tried copy-pasting ~50 lines of `<Text>` to see if it's my fault, but it only displays a very few number of line. I can't find any document that says clearly about this so hope someone has faced this before.

**Issue 2:**

When I switch tab using Footer, if the previous tab position is bottom, the new tab position is also bottom, not "auto scroll" to the top. Can somebody show me how to get new tab to top?

A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! I somehow made another `<Content>` inside a `<Content>`, replacing it by a `<View>` makes the first issue go away.

But the position one is still driving me crazy :(